# Android Spinner widget

Tags: android

I am developing a new kind of app for the android phones.
I have problem with my Spinner widget, i think it because of the classes and the Vars but i don't realy know what is it the real problem... this is the code:

```
public class BHac extends Activity 
 {

String[] tzIDs = new String[10000];
String sText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bhac);

    try
    {
        tzIDs = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tzIDs);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setSelection(1);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        try 
        {

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
                {

                    sText= tzIDs[pos];

                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                    String timestamp = formatter.format(TimeZone.getTimeZone(sText));

                    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    t.setText(timestamp);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
                {
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text =  "Android Exception [BHAC]" + x;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            Log.e ("WHWJDAKDJKAJKLDJSKKKKKK", "dadada" + x);
        }
```

this is the LogCat:

```
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
05-06 19:53:50.950: E/global(334):  at smale.app.dc.SmaleActivity$1.run(SmaleActivity.java:58)
05-06 19:53:51.748: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 62K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 2034K/2137K, paused 98ms
05-06 19:56:36.559: D/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
05-06 19:56:36.559: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at smale.app.dc.BHac$1.onItemSelected(BHac.java:62)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-06 19:56:36.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Please post your logcat errors. Without it we have no idea what is happening either, we can only guess. Perhaps `tzIDs` is null or `pos` is outside of `tzIDs` bounds or maybe `t` is null...

Comment: @Sam ok.. i uploaded the LogCat and add the lines from the app.

Comment: To double check: is that all of the errors? Is there a line with "caused by..." and more underneath until "... xx more"?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you findViewById is returning null would be my guess.

Without further code/layout Indo there's not much.more that can be deduced.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the line that throws the exception:

```
String timestamp = formatter.format(TimeZone.getTimeZone(sText));
```

Using your code, I believe this is what you intended:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
formatter.setTimeZone(sText);

String timestamp = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```